# Why does count() return more than 0 when there is no element in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

If there are no elements in a array, why does `count()` return more than 0?

```
if (count($_POST['tickboxes']) > 0) {
           echo "found";
}
```

$POST array structure:

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 53
    [tickboxes] => 
    [dropdowns] => 
)
```

I was expecting 0 or null.

Comment: Put result of `var_dump($_POST['tickboxes']);` in your question. I bet there is a string inside

Comment: `$_POST['tickboxes']` is set, any set variable will at least return `1` with `count`. Unset variables will return `0` (variables which contain `NULL` are not set in PHP). Arrays and Objects will return their count. [Please read the documentation of the return value](http://php.net/count).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to [`count`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/count) something that is not an array, but rather a string.

As documented, `count` returns `1` for strings, regardless of their lengths.

You can use the [`strlen`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/strlen) function instead, as it counts the number of ascii characters in that string:

```
if (strlen($_POST['tickboxes']) > 0) {
           echo "found";
}
```

Additionally, you can use the [`empty`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/empty) language construct for this, it will check if it's an empty array or a blank string, or the integer 0 or the string '0' - and that last one may cause you grief (depending on what you are doing with it, i.e. if your users can send you such input).

If `empty` would be an option for you, you can just spare that as well:

```
if ($_POST['tickboxes']) {
           echo "found";
}
```

Don't forget to check if that key in the `$_POST` array exists if you do so. If you're unsure, `empty` won't give you any warning:

```
if (!empty($_POST['tickboxes'])) {
           echo "found";
}
```

Comment: `count` does not convert the first parameter, it just accepts a value and will return as documented.

Comment: @hakre it's documented that way because behind the scenes anything that is not an array is converted to an array first. Instead of confusing users with those details they just documented what the net result is.

Comment: Ariel, what you say is wrong. [It's checked against the type with a switch statement and then returned accordingly](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/standard/array.c#298). There is no conversion into an array.

Comment: @hakre You are correct, and I am surprised. I guess they did it that way as an optimization since there is no reason to convert it only to ignore the result.

Comment: As long as I remember `count` worked that way. An older description was something like "the number of values" and skalars just have one value. You normally use it with arrays or objects, maybe that's why this comes now on top of the manual page. Especially with objects this is nice ([countable interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php)).

Answer (score 3):

That would be because your variable is not an array. Try `echo count('');` and you'll see it returns 1 while `count(array())` will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

i think @Ariel solve it

if you sending data from html form you can use  tamperdata addons in firefox

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/

this will help you :)